# Using timers which continue only if the callback has been executed till the end

Tags: c#

I'm developing a game server and I need to handle some events. By exemple : a player want to attack another player. If he can, an event is executed every seconds which deals damage.

There's a sample code which is not working, but I hope you will get the idea !

```
using System.Timers;
public class Test
{
    public static Timer FightTimer;
    // Session is the player
    public static void Main(Session Session)
    {


        FightTimer = new Timer(1000); // one second interval

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        FightTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 1 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
        FightTimer.Interval = 1000;
        FightTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void Fight(object attacker)
    {
        FightTimer.stop();
        // get the session
        Session Session = (Session)attacker;

        if (Session.CharacterInfo.IsDestroy == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Ok here will be calculated all damage and ect...
        // if there's no others "return" for stopping the execution we can let the timer call
        // the callback again. if not, the timer is stopped and disposed

        FightTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Well I hope you got the idea, my problem is I don't know at all how I can do that so I hope you will be able to help me. Thanks in advance !

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: My question is, how to implement that ?

Comment: You want us to just write your code for you? I don't think so.

Comment: I'm asking how I can tell to the timer to stop and dispose if the callback is not executed till the end, so if there's a "return;" the timer will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the [System.Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use the [System.Timer.Enabled property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Setting the property to `false` will stop the timer ticking - it will not `raise the Elapsed event` anymore.

What need to be changed in your code:

- make the timer variable global (or pass it to the desired method)
- then use `FightTimer.Enabled = false;` to stop it

The modified code (one possible solution):

```
using System.Timers;
public class Test
{
    // Session is the player
    static Timer FightTimer = null;

    public static void Main(Session Session)
    {
        FightTimer = new Timer(1000); // one second interval

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        FightTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Fight);

        // Set the Interval to 1 seconds
        FightTimer.Interval = 1000;
        FightTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void Fight(object attacker)
    {
        // get the session
        Session Session = (Session)attacker;

        if (Session.CharacterInfo.IsDestroy == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Ok here will be calculated all damage and ect...
        // if there's no others "return" for stopping the execution we can let the timer call
        // the callback again. if not, the timer is stopped and disposed
        FightTimer.Enabled = false;
        // modify to your needs
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use it within the callback ?

Comment: @linkpad: Yes.  Typically the first line of a timer call back is to disable the timer.  You'll need to turn it back on at the end of the callback.

Comment: @Linkpad why don't you try?

Comment: Well, I edited my first post and @EZI I was not sure if it was "well written" that's why I'm asking. Anyway, if I set Enabled to false the timer will be disposed ?

Comment: No, the timer will not be `disposed` - it will stop executing periodically the callback function (in this case `Fight`). At this time the `FightTimer` variable is still alive! If you are asking about code review, than [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably better suited.

Comment: Well for disposing it, can I do this inside the callback ? `FightTimer.Dispose();` Anyway thanks for code review, didn't know that exist. It was not really a code review because I didn't know exactly how I can make it